# How to return modified items with custom FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo, custom-controls

I am adding a label attribute to items in a custom FilteringSelect widget store so that they get displayed with an icon.

```
var data = this.store.data;
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    data[i].label = data[i].needsIcon ? "<div class='labelIcon'></div> " : "";
    data[i].label += data[i].value;
}
```

This is all good for displaying the icon in front of items in the dropdown, but when an item is selected, the label is now part of the object. Is there a way to modify the custom widget so that it returns items without the "label" attribute:

```
var myItem = customSelectWidget.item; // How to return the item without "label"???
```

Comment: Can you add FilteringSelect declaration and also store declaration with sample data? It's very unclear what are you trying to achieve here, because you are setting label and then don't want it, do you want store item to remain same as before change?

Comment: I am using a custom FilteringSelect widget to display a choice of identities and I am using icons in the dropdown list to differentiate between identity types. That is why I need a label. However, once the identity has been selected, it needs to be posted and the server-side code, which I do not have access to, does not accept any unexpected attributes. So I need to remove the label attribute I am using to display the icon when *customSelectWidget.item* is used to retrieve the selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use some dom manipulation like this : (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/wMfQV/))

```
select = new FilteringSelect({
    id : "myContainer",
    store : store,
    searchAttr : "label"
}, "mySelect");

select.on("search", function(){
    var menuItems = query(".dijitMenuItem", select.dropDown.domNode);
    array.forEach(menuItems, function(menuItem){
            switch(menuItem.innerText){
            case  "Apples" :
                domClass.add(menuItem, "apple");
                break;
            case "Pears" :
                domClass.add(menuItem, "pear");
                break;
            }
    });
});
```

And then customize your menuItem nodes with css classes like :

```
.claro div.dijitMenuItem.apple, .claro div.dijitMenuItem.pear {
    padding-left : 18px;
}

.claro div.dijitMenuItem.apple {
    background : url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mad-science/yellow-submarine/16/APPLE-icon.png) left no-repeat;
}
.claro div.dijitMenuItem.pear{
    background : url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconicon/veggies/16/pear-icon.png) left no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This can definitely work! Will post feedback once I get time to try it.

Comment: I finally had time to try this out and it works very well. Thanks again. I just made a slight modification: `            this.on("search", function() {
                var menuItems = this.dropDown.items;
                if ( menuItems ) {
                    var menuNodes = this.dropDown.domNode.children;
                    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
                        if (menuItems[i].needsIcon) {
                            domClass.add(menuNodes[i+1], "labelIcon");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });`